# How can I validate Facebook post IDs

Tags: facebook, validation, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Assume a facebook game that rewards users with virtual-currency usable in the game for posting events from the game on their wall.

Using the IFrame method, I get on the client a JavaScript callback with the `{ post_id: 'some id' }` when the user completes the post successfully, and life is good.

While the post takes place on the client, I have to address the server and commit the reward for the user, providing the server with the post-id, and that is done using some form of JSONP HTTP request.

Stripping away the defense mechanisms against abuse that make sure that users will not overdo with posts and annoy all their friends with the game, lets focus on the problem:

- since server calls can be easily mocked using utils like `curl` or `fiddler`, after signing the request and all, I still need to make sure that the post-id that came in this request is in deed a real `post_id` that came from facebook, and that this post is **in-deed** visible on the user's wall - at least for his friends...

(because, no, post as private post that only you can see should not reward you with virtual-currency)

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What you are describing in the first sentence would be a violation of Platform Policies – IV. Application Integration Points, Point 1 -- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe is absolutely right: [Facebook Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) (specifically Section IV, Item 1) prohibit the functionality you describe.

Breaking a policy and circumventing restrictions (which is another item against the policy...) is never the "best way" to do anything. But... what you describe is possible. I'd explain how but it's probably also against [Stack Exchange policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal) to do so:

> 3 Subscriber Content
>
> [...]
>
> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber content that [...] (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another[.]

Just know it's possible, maybe figure out how to do it for the satisfaction, and then move on without implementing what you ask.

Comment: I read, and I do not believe my eyes... frankly, my product-designer is following the trend of the genre - where games incentive "like" and "wall-posts" and invite-friends with in-game benefits, such as power-ups and resources - and we have to do the same to cope with the compatition. It could be a misreading...

Comment: Facebook has a separate bunch of game guidelines and even a few API calls specific to games. I still don't think you'll be able to do exactly what you've asked (without breaking policy), but [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/games/) might give you some alternatives you can present to your product-designer. Here's a [policy supplement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/) that might be a good alternative, as well.